# How to refresh an http GET request with python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to refresh an http GET request for a url. Each time I run the script it gets the information I want but doesnt refresh the time stamps to update the content. Im using aiohttp as the module.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time


url = 'https://api.btcmarkets.net/v3/markets/LTC-AUD/ticker'


async def get_data(session):
    request = await session.request('GET', url, )

    response = await request.text()
    print(response)


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        while True:
            await get_data(session)
            time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: The timestamp is refreshed server-side so you *can't* update it. Just wait longer between your requests to the API.

Comment: @baduker Yep just ran it for 5 min and the time stamp updated. Thanks alot for the help.